# Http controller parameter object defined as DTO or other?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

RPC in Internet transport layer, use dto is reasonable.  Http controller? If all controller are used by front end,  parameter defined as VO?

Comment: Could you explain better what are you asking?

Comment: @GetMapping("/bankcard/list")
List<BankCardVO> listBankCard(ListBankParam param);
rest api, Can parameter object(ListBankParam) defined as ListBankDTO ?  or use BankCardVO ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are asking whether the argument of the rest controller method can be a DTO.

Well it will depend on the framework you use. The http parameters are strings.

If the framework has an utility mechanism (probably an annotation) that lets you map the http params you receive into a DTO you supply as the rest controller method arg, there's no problem in the arg being a DTO.

If the framework doesn't have such utility (it just maps each http param into an string arg of the rest controller method), then you have to build manually the DTO in the rest controller method.

I don't know if Spring has such an utility annotation similar to @PathVariable but for gathering multiple request params into a DTO object.

**UPDATE:**

Spring @RequestBody annotation deserializes the JSON into the java object argument of the rest controller method. So, the arg annotated with @RequestBody is a DTO.

DDD says nothing about which type must be the params of a rest api. They can be either a DTO or Strings, it doesn't matter. If they where strings, you would have to construct the DTO by yourself. Using @RequestBody, Spring framework does it for you.

Comment: I use spring @RequestBody to transfer object data by rest controller. This object data can named xxxDTO?  What is the object type of the rest controller params,  In Domain-Driven Design.

Answer (score 1):

In java, an object that is carries between process is named following the camel case notation and having the `DTO` suffix. 
e.g. `ServiceMessageDTO`

DTO stands for data transfer object.

This applies also to the request body parameters from the rest webmethods.